# Highish current constant current source design?

Tags: constant-current

I need a design for a constant current source that can deliver a hefty current at around 12 volts with at least 1-2 amps, preferably up to 5. Every current source I've seen uses BJTs or resistors that are submitted to the same current as the load, but I don't want to dish out the money for a 100w resistor or BJT.

I'd like to avoid an LM317, though I'll do it if it's the best option. Is there a good constant current source design that can deliver 12v @ 2-5A using, say, op-amps or mosfets?

The output doesn't need to be perfectly stable, I just want to prevent any components (namely electrolytic caps) from blowing up.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Do you want a constant current regardless of the voltage compliance? Or do you want a constant voltage, but to limit the current to a maximum value?

Comment: @jonk Sorry, I can see where that confusion comes from. I want a circuit with a maximum of 12 volts, but the voltage is lowered as needed to maintain a current at or below a set value. Perhaps "constant" current isn't the right term. Current limiting perhaps?

Comment: @jonk My main issue is that every "constant current" or "current limiting" circuit I've seen online works with at most 20mA which is _far_ too low for my purposes. And they can't be scaled up easily without buying expensive high power resistors or other components.

Comment: So you want a programmable \$0-5\:\textrm{A}\$ current limit with a compliance voltage of up to \$12\:\textrm{V}\$ and you want it to be efficient (in the sense that it doesn't dissipate much on its own?) What exactly are you expecting to drive with this?

Comment: @jonk Doesn't have to be programmable per se. That's just an example of the range I'm needing. 0.5A is too low, 10A is too much, I can make do with 1A, but 2-5A is ideal. But yes about it being relatively efficient. Thanks for the help, by the way. :)

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-24V-To-12V-12A-High-Power-LED-Driver-Constant-Current-Voltage-Buck-Module-MK-/311434038867?hash=item4882ea4e53:g:3FkAAOSwyDxXh-4d

Comment: @jonk The issue with that ebay listing is that my load will draw as much as it can deliver and things will start frying.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You can tweak the current limit with that device to what you want. I guess I have no idea what you are trying to actually achieve. What are you driving?

Comment: @jonk "You can tweak the current limit with that device to what you want" Oh duh, I didn't notice that. Yes, that's the sort of thing I'm looking for. However, is there a schematic that accomplishes the same goal with relatively common parts? I'm looking to build with what I have available without buying new components.

Comment: @jonk On thinking about it and doing a bit of searching, I found another buck converter with good efficiency that does what I want. (Similar to the one you showed) Thanks again. If you make an answer with the ebay link I'll gladly mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Nah. No need for the points. I'm just glad you found something that will do the job. Doing a switcher (efficient) with spare parts is "hard." Doing a linear circuit is easy, but that's exactly what you said you didn't want to do. So that's that, I suppose.

Comment: @Daffy You can leave your own answer and if someone thinks it's flawed or has problems you will get comments about it. Is the load tied to 0 volts i.e. the current limiting as to be done in the positive feed?